# Get document object from URL via javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, parsing, url, dom

I am working on my first web scraper, I have written JavaScript code the extracts the information I am looking for on a specific webpage. I am doing this all by using the JavaScript `document` object. I am trying to load a `document` object by URL so that I can do multiple instances of this at once. I have 10 web pages at a time all with different content but with the same structure, so I can grab them each individually if I go to the page but I am trying to get a `document` object by URL. I tried loading an `iframe` via URL and then grabbing that content but it did not work and or gave me cross origin errors. Any ideas?

Comment: It is unlikely that we can help you if you don't include the code you're using and ask a specific question about that code.  If your web scraper is in a browser, you will not be able to access cross origin sites.

Comment: Can I see what have you tried so far??..and basically whats going wrong?